# How to check and uncheck the checkboxes when clicking on the link?

Tags: javascript, checkbox

I have to check and uncheck the checkboxes inside a certain div when clicking on a link inside the same div. I have to have the same type of code but, I need the script to work perfectly too. I must have the checkboxes inside the children and the button should also be a child. The HTML code is below.

```
<div class="parent">

<div class="child">

    <a class="filter-check-btn">button</a>

    <div class="all-checkboxes">
        <div class="sep-chk">
            <label class="rad">
                <input class="filter-chk-box" type="checkbox" checked> Checkbox
            </label>
        </div>
        <div class="sep-chk">
            <label class="rad">
                <input class="filter-chk-box" type="checkbox" checked> Checkbox
            </label>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>

<div class="child">

    <div class="all-checkboxes">
        <div class="sep-chk">
            <label class="rad">
                <input class="filter-chk-box" type="checkbox" checked> Checkbox
            </label>
        </div>
        <div class="sep-chk">
            <label class="rad">
                <input class="filter-chk-box" type="checkbox" checked> Checkbox
            </label>
        </div>
        <div class="sep-chk">
            <label class="rad">
                <input class="filter-chk-box" type="checkbox" checked> Checkbox
            </label>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
</div>
```

And the script is below

```
$(".filter-check-btn").on('click', function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('active');
    $(this).parent().parent().children(".filter-chk-box").prop('checked', false);
});

$(".filter-check-btn.active").on('click', function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('active');
    $(this).parent().parent().children(".filter-chk-box").prop('checked', true);
});
```

Comment: can you please explain bit more and what you tried

Comment: I dont see a link (`<a>`) tag. Also you can try something like `<a onclick="toggleCheckBox()"`. In this function, update checked property of checkbox to true and **return false**.

Comment: can you do that with "for" tag in label , and id in input[checkbox]

Eg: <label for="one">Check</label> <input type="checkbox" id="one">

now they can be on any div , any parenthesis, without javascript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change your jQuery code like this:

```
$(".filter-check-btn").on('click', function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('active');
    if ($(this).hasClass("active"))
    $(this).parent().parent().find(".filter-chk-box").prop('checked', true);
    else
    $(this).parent().parent().find(".filter-chk-box").prop('checked', false);
});
```

[FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/cmfwmocr/1/)

Comment: Thank you, @Darth. This is what I wanted.